# Any way to clear the results of RAD's own code coverage tool (in RAD 7.5)?

Tags: code-coverage, ibm-rad

So, RAD 7.5 comes with IBM's own code coverage tool which seems alright.  However, after running the any of the JUnit tests which highlight all your files with code coverage stats, I can't find any way of clearing the results so that I'm not staring at a sea of red and green everywhere.  Looks like Christmas on my screen :)

Anyway, the only way I've found so far is to go to Properties for a code-coverage enabled project and untick 'Enable Code Coverage' under 'Code Coverage' (followed by 'Apply'), which strangely clears the results for every project.  I then retick it (and click 'OK').  That process is a bit lame, and I'd prefer a keyboard shortcut or GUI button to do this instead.  Any hints or tips out there?

Answer (score 2):

In RAD 8, I go to Run > Code Coverage > Remove indicators. This will clear the indicators until you start your server.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, good to know for when we eventually upgrade to 8.